# LaTeX subfloat with subcaption package: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: latex, package, figures

I want to make a figure consisting of two subfigures.  Having read the Wikipedia subentry on [subfloats](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats), I tried to follow it exactly, so I did not use the `subfig` or `subfigure` package, only the `caption` and `subcaption` packages.  Nevertheless, I am getting a `Missing number, treated as zero` error, pointing to the line with `\begin{subfigure}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
% In preamble:
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


% In document:
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A caption.}
\label{fig:my-figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: NB:  The subfig and subfigure packages are both supposed to be deprecated; hence I used subcaption instead.

Comment: you'll get better luck at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Duplicate posted: [Subfloat with subcaption package: Missing number, treated as zero](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69336/5764)